# Burninate [cratedata]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

A [Crate.IO](https://crate.io/about/team/) developer, [mfussenegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1333061/mfussenegger?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), has been replacing [cratedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cratedata) tags with [crate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crate), with comment:

> replace cratedata tag with crate. "cratedata" isn't used anymore on crate.io and on github

I originally rejected some of his edits until I realized what was going on, and have since reverted and have replaced the tags myself on the rest of the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cratedata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cratedata) no longer has any questions associated with it.

It is now...

[image: BURNINATED]

Comment: Well, not the right way to do it, but it doesn't exactly look like [this problem](http://www.moddb.com/mods/too-many-crates).